# Coding Explanation: variable set with bitwise OR character in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-or

I ran across some JS today that I didn't understand, and googling bitwise operations isn't really helping me out. Can someone explain the below?

```
     function createExcerpt(string, maxLength) {
          // Set a default value of maxLength of 110
          maxLength = maxLength | 110;
          ...
```

Although I read that the pipe character is a bitwise OR, I'm at a loss as to what is happening in the above. 
If I should post more of the function for context, just let me know.

Comment: Usually default arguments are done with logical OR (`||`)... given that comment, looks like a mistake. Bitwise OR would _not_ "set a default value"

Comment: (Although, using `||` for default args [isn't great practice](http://www.codereadability.com/javascript-default-parameters-with-or-operator/), despite how often you see it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the presence of that comment in the preceding line, this looks to be a simple typo.

Setting of defaults would generally be done with the *logical* `or` operator,  `||`, so it's almost certainly meant to be:

```
maxLength = maxLength || 110;
```

However, this is actually a bad idea since, if `maxLength` has been set to a falsey value (like zero), it will be replaced with the default. That *may* be what you want but it's by no means clear.

I would probably opt for the *slightly* more verbose but definitely clearer:

```
if (maxLength === undefined) { maxLength = 110; }
```

It still fits on one line and the intent is very specific.

And a better way, assuming you have ES6 available to you, would be to use default arguments baked directly into the function call:

```
function createExcerpt(string, maxLength = 110) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a mistake.  Logical OR (||) is used as a null coalescing operator.  Bitwise ORing will not have the effect indicated in the comment.  You can test it yourself by running it through some tests.

```
110 | 110 = 110
120 | 110 = 126
90 | 110 = 126
null | 110 = 110
50 | 110 = 126
200 | 110 = 238
```

You can see from just a few examples that the result will be pretty counter-intuitive to someone passing a "maxlength" argument.